# Vim Code Completion Problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

For about 3 weeks, I have been tweaking my vim to get it running for the code completion. The strange thing is that if I write a non ROS-related code, it just works, but when I write a ROS-related one, it does not work (including non ROS-related line, say I type std::), it won't complete any..

I really need this vim to have this code completion working..Hope any Vim experts out there can guide me on this..Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I've observed one thing in non ROS-related code, if it is still not working if I type std::, but it is working if I type rect. (will be autocompleted with some members in the class). I think if I can resolve with "::" in non ROS-related code, it will also work in ROS-related code..hopefully.

I've also tried to follow [one](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C++_code_completion) tutorial to reinstall my code completion. At the bottom of the [tutorial](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/C++_code_completion), there is a test to try to type "std::" in .cpp file. I'm even not able to have it worked.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9669/vim-code-completion-problem/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found this yesterday:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3302 and
http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense/
Maybe these work for you.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2011-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2011-04-07**:
I don't know, I didn't try these out.

**Comment by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on 2011-04-06**:
I'm not so sure about using gccsense for ROS-related code, how to configure our .vimrc?